Attribute search_after not returning expected results in opensearch
I have sample data set records as below:
{
  "took": 22,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 0,
    "successful": 0,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 16,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "naqp-uat-library-index",
        "_id": "a2bafe29-ab36-412a-a87d-f94b76ffb938",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "documentId": "a2bafe29-ab36-412a-a87d-f94b76ffb938",
          "documentType": "mil-i",
          "recordLastUpdatedBy": "NAQ Event",
          "recordLastUpdatedAt": "2024-12-04T06:30:59+0000",
          "recordCreatedBy": "Rusty Brown",
          "recordCreatedAt": "2024-12-04T06:26:28+0000",
          "businessMetaData": [
            {
              "dtcBitPend": "1",
              "dtcCode": "0",
              "messageType": "CRITICAL",
              "msgId": "Test_101",
              "configIds": [
                "9900798",
                "612661"
              ],
              "messageRuleType": "C",
              "dtcBitCurr": "1",
              "dtcBitPerm": "1",
              "dtcBitHist": "1",
              "dtcBitTestFail": "0",
              "dtcMessageId": "153431"
            }
          ],
          "primaryKey": "153431",
          "documentLanguage": "EN",
          "author": "mil-i",
          "documentSummary": "MessageUpdate",
          "documentDate": "2023-10-06T17:09:09+0000",
          "documentName": "Mili Config Message",
          "documentTitle": "Test",
          "documentStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "documentNotes": "MiliTestMessage",
          "fileFormat": "HTML",
          "version": 1,
          "mimeType": "application/pdf",
          "businessCreatedAt": "2023-10-06T17:09:09+0000",
          "businessCreatedBy": "Rusty Brown",
          "businessLastUpdatedAt": "2024-12-04T05:30:42+0000",
          "businessLastUpdatedBy": "Annapoorna Nagireddi"
        },
        "sort": [
          1733293588000
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "naqp-uat-library-index",
        "_id": "476cea23-8d58-42c9-ba2a-0fc7e296bfac",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "documentId": "476cea23-8d58-42c9-ba2a-0fc7e296bfac",
          "documentType": "mil-i",
          "recordLastUpdatedBy": "NAQ Event",
          "recordLastUpdatedAt": "2024-11-06T10:54:18+0000",
          "recordCreatedBy": "system",
          "recordCreatedAt": "2024-09-16T07:44:38+0000",
          "businessMetaData": [
            {
              "dtcBitPend": "1",
              "dtcCode": "123",
              "messageType": "CRITICAL",
              "msgId": "1234",
              "configIds": [
                "612661",
                "611100",
                "2125740"
              ],
              "messageRuleType": "M",
              "dtcBitCurr": "1",
              "dtcBitPerm": "1",
              "dtcBitHist": "1",
              "dtcBitTestFail": "0",
              "dtcMessageId": "153409"
            }
          ],
          "primaryKey": "153409",
          "documentLanguage": "EN",
          "author": "mil-i",
          "documentSummary": "teste",
          "documentDate": "2024-09-16T07:44:19+0000",
          "documentName": "Mili Config Message",
          "documentTitle": "test",
          "documentStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "documentNotes": "test",
          "fileFormat": "HTML",
          "version": 1,
          "mimeType": "application/pdf",
          "businessCreatedAt": "2024-09-16T07:44:19+0000",
          "businessCreatedBy": "system",
          "businessLastUpdatedAt": "2024-11-06T09:54:04+0000",
          "businessLastUpdatedBy": "system"
        },
        "sort": [
          1726472678000
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "naqp-uat-library-index",
        "_id": "1899c15a-a9e7-4c16-93cb-be3595643ed1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "documentId": "1899c15a-a9e7-4c16-93cb-be3595643ed1",
          "documentType": "mil-i",
          "recordCreatedBy": "DailyRefresh",
          "recordCreatedAt": "2024-09-10T12:23:44+0000",
          "businessMetaData": [
            {
              "dtcBitPend": "1",
              "dtcCode": "P1672",
              "messageType": "CRITICAL",
              "msgId": "153429",
              "configIds": [
                "612661",
                "228",
                "101037"
              ],
              "messageRuleType": "C",
              "dtcBitCurr": "1",
              "dtcBitPerm": "1",
              "dtcBitHist": "1",
              "dtcBitTestFail": "0",
              "dtcMessageId": "153429"
            }
          ],
          "primaryKey": "153429",
          "documentLanguage": "EN",
          "author": "mil-i",
          "documentSummary": "<p> Avoid junk </p>",
          "documentDate": "2024-02-05T10:00:10+0000",
          "documentName": "Mili Config Message",
          "documentTitle": "<h><b> Good Health </h></b>",
          "documentStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "documentNotes": "<h> you are all good</h>",
          "fileFormat": "HTML",
          "version": 2,
          "mimeType": "application/pdf",
          "businessCreatedAt": "2024-02-05T10:00:10+0000",
          "businessCreatedBy": "DailyRefresh",
          "businessLastUpdatedAt": "2024-09-10T12:23:25+0000",
          "businessLastUpdatedBy": "Rusty Brown"
        },
        "sort": [
          1725971024000
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "naqp-uat-library-index",
        "_id": "470acf62-1adb-496a-a020-affcc987eb01",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "documentId": "470acf62-1adb-496a-a020-affcc987eb01",
          "documentType": "mil-i",
          "recordCreatedBy": "DailyRefresh",
          "recordCreatedAt": "2024-09-10T12:23:44+0000",
          "businessMetaData": [
            {
              "dtcBitPend": "1",
              "dtcCode": "P1672",
              "messageType": "CRITICAL",
              "msgId": "153429",
              "configIds": [
                "612661",
                "228",
                "101037"
              ],
              "messageRuleType": "C",
              "dtcBitCurr": "1",
              "dtcBitPerm": "1",
              "dtcBitHist": "1",
              "dtcBitTestFail": "0",
              "dtcMessageId": "153429"
            }
          ],
          "primaryKey": "153429",
          "documentLanguage": "EN",
          "author": "mil-i",
          "documentSummary": "<p> Avoid junk </p>",
          "documentDate": "2021-12-17T19:59:47+0000",
          "documentName": "Mili Config Message",
          "documentTitle": "<h><b> Good Health </h></b>",
          "documentStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "documentNotes": "<h> you are all good</h>",
          "fileFormat": "HTML",
          "version": 1,
          "mimeType": "application/pdf",
          "businessCreatedAt": "2021-12-17T19:59:47+0000",
          "businessCreatedBy": "DailyRefresh",
          "businessLastUpdatedAt": "2024-09-10T12:23:25+0000",
          "businessLastUpdatedBy": "Rusty Brown"
        },
        "sort": [
          1725971024000
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

I am using search_after attribute in opensearch to set pagination for above data. I have total of 50k records.
For below query, but after 10,000 records pagination is not working. Next 10,000 records are not being fetched. If I set size to some smaller number like 100 its working as expected.
{
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "documentName": {
                            "query": "Mili Config Message",
                            "slop": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "documentType": {
                            "value": "mil-i"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "search_after" : [1723209664000],
        "sort": [
        {
            "recordCreatedAt": "desc"
        }
    ]
}

This query is working as expected upto 10,000 records, but after that its failing. Records are returned but not as expected.

You should use the last result’s sort values to retrieve the next result by using the search_after parameter:
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/searching-data/paginate/#the-search_after-parameter
Did you do that?

Hi @MusabDogan. Yes I n above query you can see I have used search_after attribute, upto 10,000 records its working as expected when i set size to small number, But when i try with size 10,000 and use search_after then its not working as expected. It's not returning next 10,000 records

Looks like there is a problem. Please try with pit + search_after and let's check the results.
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/searching-data/point-in-time/#pagination-with-pit-and-search_after

It's not returning next 10,000 records - how did you detected that?

